# Statement Leakage in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Statement Leakage in JDBC:

```
  pstmt =
StatementLeakage : An open JDBC Statement is not closed on all paths. This can cause a transaction or Statement resources to remain active indefinitely, slowing or preventing access to the database by other requests.: for (object created at line = TunnelDBHandler:139, type = java.sql.PreparedStatement), object used at prepareStatement() @ TunnelDBHandler:139 
                 dbManager
                    .getConnection()
                   .prepareStatement(
                      "update TUNNEL_STORE set IS_TUNNEL_OPEN=? where TUNNEL_ID=?");
```

Comment: The *actual* problem here is that `pstmt` had a prior value which you have not closed.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `finally` block and call `close()` on all of your [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)(s), [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)(s) and [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)(s). As a very rough example,

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  // ...
  // get a statement for stmt
  // get a resultset from the stmt
  // ...
  while (rs.next()) {

  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (rs != null) {
    try {
      rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
  }
  if (stmt != null) {
    try {
      stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
  }
  if (conn != null) {
    try {
      conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
  }
}
```